# How to Load data in AngularJS when control loads?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an AngularJS controller; On the first load the data is not fetching from db

```html
app.controller("ProductPopupController", function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog, $filter) {
    console.log("ProductPopupController");

    var allGroups = [];
    $http.get('UserDetail/GetAllUsers').success(function (response) {
        console.log("I got the data I requested");
        //console.log(response);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            allGroups.push({
                UserName: response[i].UserName,
                _id: response[i]._id
            });
        }
    });


    console.log(allGroups);

    var allGroups = [
                    { 'UserName': 'one', '_id': 1 },
                    { 'UserName': 'two', '_id': 2 },
                    { 'UserName': 'three', '_id': 3 },
                    { 'UserName': 'four', '_id': 4 },
                    { 'UserName': 'five', '_id': 5 },
                    { 'UserName': 'six', '_id': 6 },
                    { 'UserName': 'sixteen', '_id': 7 },
                    { 'UserName': 'seven', '_id': 8 }

                ];

    console.log(allGroups);
```

In this code I am getting the value from second array. Not getting from the db. After any event it will load from db. Whats wrong I have done here?

Comment: Just FYI `$http().success()` and `.error` have been deprecated. They were helper methods that wrapped `.then` and `.catch` and caused issues if you tried to use `.success` half way through a `$http` promise chain. `.then` and `.catch` should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because `$http.get()` is Asynchronous.  You are making the call to `$http.get()`, then immediately making the call to `console.log(allGroups)` before the result has been retrieved.

As soon as the data has been retrieved and the `.success()` fires,  Angular will fire a digest cycle, causing the data to update and be pushed into the array.  However, this happens long after the controller has finished, so the data is never printed in the `console.log()`.

Comment: Any solution for to achieve my result on load?

Comment: It is happening on load already, but the browser doesn't wait for it to load before doing other tasks.  That's the point of an async call.  Don't try to log the async call outside the `.success()`, instead, initialize the array *first*, then log the change to the array inside the `.success()`. (*side note:* `.success()` is deprecated, use `.then()` instead).

Comment: Actually my requirement is to load a md-chip by using md-autocomplete. In the above example how to achieve this by using .then()?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. If a display element isn't showing the data that is being loaded, you should show the code for that element in your example.  As for using `.then`, there are plenty of articles describing it's use, I just didn't post any because it didn't seem to be the main point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that  `$http.get('UserDetail/GetAllUsers')` is an asynchronous call. You print out your variable `allGroups` before you receive the response of your request. If you add a `console.log` at the end of `success` function, you will see, that the data is set.

Answer (score 0):

This is my full code to load md-chips (Angular material) by using md-qutocomplete

```js
app.controller("ProductPopupController", function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog, $filter) {
    console.log("ProductPopupController");

    var allGroups = [];
    $http.get('UserDetail/GetAllUsers').success(function (response) {
        console.log("I got the data I requested");
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            allGroups.push({
                UserName: response[i].UserName,
                _id: response[i]._id
            });
        }
        console.log(1);
        console.log(allGroups);
    });

    console.log(2);
    

    var allGroups = [
                    { 'UserName': 'one', '_id': 1 },
                    { 'UserName': 'two', '_id': 2 },
                    { 'UserName': 'three', '_id': 3 },
                    { 'UserName': 'four', '_id': 4 },
                    { 'UserName': 'five', '_id': 5 },
                    { 'UserName': 'six', '_id': 6 },
                    { 'UserName': 'sixteen', '_id': 7 },
                    { 'UserName': 'seven', '_id': 8 }

    //            'one',
    //            'two',
    //            'three',
    //            'four',
    //            'five',
    //            'six',
    //            'sixteen',
    //            'seven'
                ];

    console.log(allGroups);

    $scope.queryGroups = function (search) {
        var firstPass = $filter('filter')(allGroups, search);

        return firstPass.filter(function (item) {
            return $scope.selectedGroups.indexOf(item) === -1;
        });
    };

    $scope.addGroup = function (group) {
        $scope.selectedGroups.push(group);
    };

    $scope.allGroups = allGroups.UserName;
    $scope.selectedGroups = [allGroups[0]];

    $scope.$watchCollection('selectedGroups', function () {
        $scope.availableGroups = $scope.queryGroups('');
    });

    $scope.getChipInfo = function (chip_info) {
        console.log(chip_info);
    }
```